# How to insert php snippet into Parent theme file from child theme functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My parent theme has a php file (/inc/mega-menu.php) that I can't override from the child theme (this would be the easiest thing but no solutions I found on here worked)

In this file there's a section of code:

```
<div class="cs-entry__inner cs-entry__content">

    <?php csco_get_post_meta( array( 'category' ), false, true, 'mega_menu_post_meta' ); ?>

    <?php the_title( '<h6 class="cs-entry__title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a></h6>' ); ?>

    <?php csco_get_post_meta( array( 'author', 'date', 'views', 'shares', 'comments' ), false, true, 'mega_menu_post_meta' ); ?>

</div>
```

This creates the menu item for the mega menu when in use. I want to add in the_excerpt below the title, so the user can add some text to the menu item....but I don't know how to insert it there since I can't override the parent theme file, and don't want to modify it directly.

Ideally would look like this:

```
<div class="cs-entry__inner cs-entry__content">

    <?php csco_get_post_meta( array( 'category' ), false, true, 'mega_menu_post_meta' ); ?>

    <?php the_title( '<h6 class="cs-entry__title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a></h6>' ); ?>

    <p class="cs-entry__excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p>

    <?php csco_get_post_meta( array( 'author', 'date', 'views', 'shares', 'comments' ), false, true, 'mega_menu_post_meta' ); ?>

</div>
```

with the cs-entry__excerpt div added below the_title.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way.But how do you think about add hook to `the_title`?

add `mega menu` post type and use this code.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'add_excerpt_to_mega_menu', 20, 2);

function change_woocommerce_single_title($title, $id) {
   $post_type = get_post_type($id);

   if ( $post_type == 'mega_menu') // you should change this line
      $title = $title . '<p class="cs-entry__excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt($id) . '</p>';
      
    return $title;
}
```